# Can I call a promise (with a loop) inside another promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I'm trying to consume 2 services from Ebay API:
`findItemsByKeywords(keyword)`: return a list of items(object);
`getItemTransactions(itemId)`: return a list of item's transactions(object);

After calling `findItemsByKeywords` and get the returned items list, I need to call `getItemTransactions` and get the transactions for each one of that items and create a new list with them.

I'm using Node.js, Express, Ejs and MongoDB

My code works for one interaction only.

```
Error:
Error: unable to connect to database at mongodb://localhost/simplysell-development
    at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/guilhermefalcao/workspace/simplysell/app.js:11:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Db.<anonymous> (/Users/guilhermefalcao/workspace/simplysell/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:169:10)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Db.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Server.listener (/Users/guilhermefalcao/workspace/simplysell/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:1786:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/guilhermefalcao/workspace/simplysell/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:274:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/guilhermefalcao/workspace/simplysell/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:334:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/guilhermefalcao/workspace/simplysell/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:270:12)
```

I'm not trying to access the database, I don't know why this error.

I'm sorry about the code and english quality, ***I'm starting now***.

Here is some code:

```
router.get('/bestsellers', (req, res, next) => {
  var i = 0;
  var findItemsByKeywordsPromise = findItemsByKeywords('iphone');
  findItemsByKeywordsPromise.then(items => {
    var getItemTransactionsPromise = getItemTransactions(items);
    return getItemTransactionsPromise;
  }).then(test => console.log(test))

});

function getItemTransactions(items) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var list = [];
    items.forEach(function (item) {

      ebay.xmlRequest({
        serviceName: 'Trading',
        opType: 'GetItemTransactions',

        // app/environment
        devId: 'xxxxxxx',
        certId: 'xxxxxxx',
        appId: 'xxxxxxx',
        sandbox: false,

        // per user
        authToken: 'xxxxxxx',

        params: {
          'ItemID': item.itemId,
          'NumberOfDays': 30
        }
      }, function (error, results) {
        list.push(results)
        resolve(list);
      });
    })
  });

}

function findItemsByKeywords(keywords) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var params = {
      keywords: [keywords],
    };

    ebay.xmlRequest({
      serviceName: 'Finding',
      opType: 'findItemsByKeywords',
      appId: 'xxxx',      // FILL IN YOUR OWN APP KEY, GET ONE HERE: https://publisher.ebaypartnernetwork.com/PublisherToolsAPI
      params: params,
      parser: ebay.parseResponseJson    // (default)
    },
      // gets all the items together in a merged array
      function itemsCallback(error, itemsResponse) {
        if (error) reject(error);

        console.log('findItemsByKeywords called');

        var items = itemsResponse.searchResult.item;

        console.log('Found', items.length, 'items');
        resolve(items);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: What are your dependencies? I've often gotten this error from including a package like Mongoose and not actually starting the mongodb server. So either comment out/remove the package, or start mongodb

Comment: @CodyGuldner 
var express = require('express'),
  router = express.Router(),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Article = mongoose.model('Article');
var ebay = require('ebay-api');

Comment: Well make sure your mongo client is started, or you will get the error

Answer (score -2, accepted):

That's right. The loop finish before the ebay api returns a value, so the resolve will return an incomplete array (list).

```
function getItemTransactions(items) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var list = [];
    items.forEach(function (item) {

      ebay.xmlRequest({
        serviceName: 'Trading',
        opType: 'GetItemTransactions',

        // app/environment
        devId: 'xxxxxxx',
        certId: 'xxxxxxx',
        appId: 'xxxxxxx',
        sandbox: false,

        // per user
        authToken: 'xxxxxxx',

        params: {
          'ItemID': item.itemId,
          'NumberOfDays': 30
        }
      }, function (error, results) {
        list.push(results)
        if (list.length == items.length) {
          resolve(list);
        }
      });
    })
  });

}
```

This is what I change, I'm resolving when the list array is completed:

```
if (list.length == items.length) {
    resolve(list);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the code we can't know why that Mongo error is happening.

But answering the answer in the title, the function `getItemTransactions` is wrong. You are calling `resolve` for each item in the array, but Promises can only be resolved once, so it will only give back the first item it resolves.

I would organize it in two functions:

```
function getItemTransaction (item) {
    return Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        ebay.xmlRequest({
            serviceName: 'Trading',
            opType: 'GetItemTransactions',

            // app/environment
            devId: 'xxxxxxx',
            certId: 'xxxxxxx',
            appId: 'xxxxxxx',
            sandbox: false,

            // per user
            authToken: 'xxxxxxx',

            params: {
                'ItemID': item.itemId,
                'NumberOfDays': 30
            }
        }, function (error, results) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }
            resolve(results);
          });
    });
}


function getItemTransactions(items) {
    var promises = items.map(function(item) {
        return getItemTransaction(item);
    });
    // Promise.all waits for all the promises to get resolved
    // and return an array of resolved promises
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

The second function might not be necessary, if you do that operation in your main code:

```
findItemsByKeywords('iphone')
    .then(items => {
        return Promise.all(items.map(item => getItemTransaction(item));
    })
    .then(test => console.log(test));
```

Comment: I wonder why this answer has a negative vote and no comments, if something is wrong please write it here~